# R Shiny change size and format of dateRangeInput widget

Tags: css, r, shiny

In my Shiny app, I have a `dateRangeInput` widget that looks like this.

[image]

1) I'd like to increase the size of the dates in the boxes and change the text from **bold** to normal.

2) Also, I would like to increase the space between the widget title and the widget input, so as to increase the height of the (`wellPanel`). I can control the width using the `width` function, but cannot seem to modify its height.

I am not an expert in CSS, so I'm having difficulty modifying this.

Here's my attempt from `ui.R`, that doesn't seem to work.

```
column(wellPanel(
tags$style(type='text/css', ".selectize-input { font-size: 20px; line-height: 24px;}"),
dateRangeInput("inp_pg1daterange", 
               label = paste('Date range selection'),
               start = min(results_combined$Date),
               end = max(results_combined$Date), 
               separator = " - ", 
               weekstart = 1

)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used `dateRangeInput`'s sample code. Two css elements to touch upon.

Updated the code to increase the gap between widget and title:

[image]

```
if (interactive()) {

  ui <- fluidPage(

    tags$title('This is my page'),

    tags$style('.input-sm {font-size: 16px; } label {font-weight: 500; margin-bottom: 15px; }'),

    dateRangeInput("daterange1", "Date range:",
                   start = "2001-01-01",
                   end   = "2010-12-31"),

    # Default start and end is the current date in the client's time zone
    dateRangeInput("daterange2", "Date range:"),

    # start and end are always specified in yyyy-mm-dd, even if the display
    # format is different
    dateRangeInput("daterange3", "Date range:",
                   start  = "2001-01-01",
                   end    = "2010-12-31",
                   min    = "2001-01-01",
                   max    = "2012-12-21",
                   format = "mm/dd/yy",
                   separator = " - "),

    # Pass in Date objects
    dateRangeInput("daterange4", "Date range:",
                   start = Sys.Date()-10,
                   end = Sys.Date()+10),

    # Use different language and different first day of week
    dateRangeInput("daterange5", "Date range:",
                   language = "de",
                   weekstart = 1),

    # Start with decade view instead of default month view
    dateRangeInput("daterange6", "Date range:",
                   startview = "decade")
  )

  shinyApp(ui, server = function(input, output) { })
}
```

Comment: thanks, your solution worked. Just another quick question: how can I increase the space between the widget title ("Date range:") and the widget input display (i.e. the dates)?

Comment: Can you please update your question. I'll check that meanwhile.